# What happens when I inject a Stateless Bean into a Stateful Bean?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, seam

I work on a large monolithic Java web system, built with JSF 1.1 and Seam Framework, running on a jBoss Server.

I have a JSF Backing Bean (Stateful by default in JSF) that injects a Stateless Bean used as a service (and annoted with @Stateless). The Stateless Service has a instance member variable declared as a List and increased by a method.

Issue:
After updating jBoss version from 5.1 EAP to 7.0, the mentioned variable (list) is taking values from other requests. This creates a bug in the system. But, the variable is inside a stateless service. Why is this happening? What should be happening in this situation?

ps: I have so many things that can be used to solve the issue, but I need to understand what is happening.

Edit: Pproblem solved, i was working with jBoss 5 and Seam Framework by several years. I was confused by a wrong jBoss 5 comportament. After read the definition to a Steteless Bean, i understand very well what are hepenning with my code:
[Java EE 1.4 Tutorial[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/#wp79775)

After update to jBoss 7, the pool of stateless beans work as expected and the system code gives a bug because a bad implementation of my team (stateless beans with so many global variables). When tho jBoss pool started works, the values started to be shared with others requests.

Comment: I don't understand your issue very well. I guess `@Stateless` is supposed to be instanced per user session? What do you mean with 'other requests'?

Comment: The values are accessible from other requests. I toggle a breakpoint to watch the list values and she has values that was puted in other operation.
Remembering: the stateles service bean was injected by seam2.2 in a JSF Stateful Backing Bean. This JSF Back Bean wich call a method in a @Stateles Service that put values inside a global list.
In a second moment, the user try to do a same operation. The Stateful class call a method (in Stateless service) again, but the global list is already filled with registries of previous operation.

Comment: Thats the supposed behaviour of stateless, I guess.

Comment: Instead of adding solved to the title, please accept the answer that helped you solve the problem or create your own answer and accept that.

Comment: I personally think requesting @JulienAubin to add the comments to his answer (improving it that way) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your stateless instance is shared among several stateful instances.

Member variables of stateless beans almost behave as global variables at runtime. So :
- if your list depends on a state, put it in a stateful bean
- otherwise keep it as is but with a purge mechanism
- the third way to be "stateful in stateless" but only in web servers consists in using ThreadLocal variables

Comment: Is a instance Variable List in a @Stateless class that are injected in a Stateful class.
Before jboss migration, the Stateless bean is ok.
After jBoss migration from 5.xx to 7.xx, the Stateless bean is taking values from other operation, as if the server is sharing a single instance of Stateles with all requests from Stateful bean.

Comment: Actually you relied on a bug of JBoss 5.x. Stateless instances are shared because their methods are not supposed to have side effects on the instances themselves.

Comment: Are you saying that Stateless Bean will share the values of its instance variables with all the other classes that inject it?
And this was not happening earlier because of a jBoss 5 problem? If it's true, so much code of the very large application was writted based on this bug and will needed to refactor.

Comment: I'm trying find this jBoss 5.xx bug documented, but i found nothing about. You know where i find any information about this bug?

Comment: If it is not a bug it is a bad implementation detail.

Now looks like @SessionScoped could be your friend, but maintaining a conversational state in a stateless bean is a smell.

Comment: I tested and, over jBoss 5, the application is returning a new instance for each Stateles Bean request. This situation was reported in jBoss 4 like a bug: [link]https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-653?_sscc=t
Second the jBoss error tacking, the issue was solved.

Comment: Sorry for you. Maybe the annotation @SessionScoped will save you. Fingers crossed.